# How to post wall in facebook

Tags: php, facebook

The way I am currently posting to a Facebook Wall is

```
<?php
   $app_id = "XXXXXXXX";
   $canvas_page = "XXXXXXXX";
   $message = "My story";
   $feed_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id="
                 . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" .urlencode($canvas_page) . "&message=" . $message;

   if (empty($_REQUEST["post_id"])) {
     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $feed_url . "'</script>");
  } else {
     echo ("Feed Post Id: " . $_REQUEST["post_id"]);
  }
?>
```

But this way, it is publishing a message on the wall of the user from the site.
Actually, I want to post the result to the wall, not any messages.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: That code looks correct for posting to the user's feed - what problem are you having with it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do either. What do you mean by message versus ???. Could you please update with a screenshot of what you have and what you desire?

Comment: like this [http://i.stack.imgur.com/b5I28.jpg] No message,post the result to the wall!